# subcollections and linearly dependent vectors

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $H$ be a collection of subsets of $$[n] := \{1, . . . , n\}$$
>   .Show that if $$|H| ≥ n+ 1$$ then there exists a subcollection $$H_0 \subseteq H $$ which is non-empty and for which each element appears in an even
>   number of sets (recall that $\emptyset$ is even...).

I know I should consider the vectors over the field $$Z^2$$ and think about linear dependencies that can be useful, but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the vector space ${\Bbb Z}_2^n$, which has dimension $n$.  Write $\def\e{{\bf e}}\e_1=(1,0,0,\ldots)$ and $\e_2=(0,1,0,\ldots)$ and so on.  For each $S$ in $H$ define a vector
$$\def\v{{\bf v}}
  \v_S=\sum_{n\in S}\e_n\ .$$
For example, if $S=\{2,3,5\}$ then $\v_S=(0,1,1,0,1,0,\ldots)$.

You now have $n+1$ vectors in an $n$-dimensional space, so they are linearly dependent.  That is, some non-trivial linear combination is zero.  Since the only coefficients available are $0$ and $1$, that means that some of the vectors add up to the zero vector.  Let the collection $H_0$ consist of the sets $S$ generating these vectors.

Now the number of times an integer $k$ occurs in sets in $H_0$ is equal to the $k$th component in the sum of the vectors generated by sets in $H_0$, and as we have seen, this sum is $0$.  But this means $0$ in ${\Bbb Z}_2$, so the sum "as an ordinary integer" is even.